# How to get specific file names in a directory and save them in a file in bash

Tags: bash, directory

I need to save the names of directories within a directory containing some special terms like "B_" and "D_" to a text file but only the file names not the whole directory but I do not know how to do it in bash. I need a text file like below as the output:

```
topout_B6_
topout__B6_
topout_B6_
topout_D2_
topout_D2_
topout_D2_
```

Comment: Could you please add an example directory layout, and a properly formatted expected output? AND what have you tried?

Comment: is simple `ls *B_* *D_*` not sufficient?

Comment: What have you already tried? You ask did not match your sample! `B_` or `B6_`?

Comment: None of the file names you specify as desired output match either of the special terms that you specify in the text of the question.  This contradiction makes it impossible to provide a good answer to your question.  You need to revise either the 'special terms' or the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If your file names are simple enough you can use glob expansion to get a list of them. This glob expansion will not include any parent directories (but may include subdirectories).

```
files=(*B_* *D_*) #stores an array of file names in $files
```

If the pattern is more complex and you require regex, you can use the [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) utility.

```
files=($(find . -type f -regex ".*[BD]_?.*))
```

Find will return the full path of the files, so you will need to strip the leading path. One approach to this is to use [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
stripped_files=$(for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo ${f##*/}; done) #iterate over array values
```

Finally you can write this out to a file. (Using [herestrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells))

```
>outfile <<<$stripped_files
```

Comment: Your command `files=$(find . -type f -regex ".*[BD]_?.*)` doesn't assigns an array to `files` (you just missed extra parentheses). It also fails when file names contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the paren catch. Re. the regex, this is just an example as it isn't clear exactly what the asker is trying to match.